# Countifs in Excel with list of names as criteria

Tags: excel, countif

I'm trying to write a countifs formula in Excel using a list of names. The following example illustrates what I would like to accomplish.

Of the members of the Beatles, who said yes? The syntax of the section in bold is where the problem lies.

=COUNTIFS(A1:A9,"YES",B1:B9,**{"JOHN","GEORGE","RINGO","PAUL"}**)

Put differently, I'm trying to "manually select" the names of people who potentially said yes.

[image]

Comment: A pivot table is the best way to do what you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you wrap your attempted formula in `SUM` function you should get the required answer, i.e.

`=SUM(COUNTIFS(A1:A9,"YES",B1:B9,{"JOHN","GEORGE","RINGO","PAUL"}))`

That works because the original formula returns an array of 4 results (one for each name) and you need the sum of those

Answer (score 2):

An alternative without COUNTIFS:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A9="YES")*(B1:B9={"JOHN","GEORGE","RINGO","PAUL"}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your formula just a tad to get what you are after.

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A1:A9,"YES",B1:B9,{"JOHN","GEORGE","RINGO","PAUL"}))
```

The array creates individual counts so you have to add the counts together.